# no appropriate default constructor available but constructor is declared

Tags: c++, qt, window, parent-child

I wanted to create a window from a mainwindow, and send it a pointer to my main window. I did it one time, and i would do it again, but the second time, I always have this error at compilation "no appropriate default constructor available"

The main window:

```
#include "costsimulator.h"
#include "ui_costsimulator.h"

#include "stonepricewindow.h"

CostSimulator::CostSimulator(AionEnhancingSimulator *parent) : ui(new Ui::CostSimulator)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

parentPtr = parent;
stonePrice = createStonePrice();
connect(ui->aionEnhancingSimulator, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showAionEnhancingSimulatorWindow()));
connect(ui->stonePriceButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showStonePriceWindow()));
}

CostSimulator::~CostSimulator()
{
delete ui;
}

void CostSimulator::showAionEnhancingSimulatorWindow()
{
this->hide();
parentPtr->show();
}

QStringList *createStonePrice()
{
QStringList *tmp = new QStringList();

tmp->push_back(QString("80-30000000"));
return (tmp);
}

void CostSimulator::showStonePriceWindow()
{
StonePriceWindow *stonepricewindow = new StonePriceWindow(this);
stonepricewindow->show();
}

QStringList *CostSimulator::getStonePrice()
{
return (stonePrice);
}
```

and the header:

```
#ifndef COSTSIMULATOR_H
#define COSTSIMULATOR_H

#include <QDialog>

#include "aionenhancingsimulator.h"

namespace Ui {
class CostSimulator;
}

class CostSimulator : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
AionEnhancingSimulator *parentPtr;
explicit CostSimulator(AionEnhancingSimulator *parent);
~CostSimulator();

QStringList *stonePrice;

QStringList *createStonePrice();
QStringList *getStonePrice();
void showStonePriceWindow();

public slots:
void showAionEnhancingSimulatorWindow();

private:
Ui::CostSimulator *ui;
};

#endif // COSTSIMULATOR_H
```

and the window that cause the problem:

```
#include "stonepricewindow.h"
#include "ui_stonepricewindow.h"
#include <QStringListModel>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QtGui>

StonePriceWindow::StonePriceWindow(CostSimulator *parent) : ui(new Ui::StonePriceWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
displayStonePriceList(parent);
}

StonePriceWindow::~StonePriceWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void StonePriceWindow::displayStonePriceList(CostSimulator *parent)
{
// To do
}
```

the header

```
#ifndef STONEPRICEWINDOW_H
#define STONEPRICEWINDOW_H

#include <QDialog>

#include "costsimulator.h"

namespace Ui {
class StonePriceWindow;
}

class StonePriceWindow : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit StonePriceWindow(CostSimulator *parent = 0);
~StonePriceWindow();

void displayStonePriceList(CostSimulator *parent);

private:
Ui::StonePriceWindow *ui;
};

#endif // STONEPRICEWINDOW_H
```

if I had this " StonePriceWindow() {}" to the header of StonePriceWindow, I have the following error: "multiple default constructors specified" and always the "no appropriate etc .."

Thanks for any help, I can't understand why.

Comment: Rather than deluge people with code, can you actually provide the _exact_ compilation error and the line it occured on.

Comment: stonepricewindow.cpp:7: erreur : C2512: 'Ui::StonePriceWindow' : no appropriate default constructor available and it is at this line : StonePriceWindow::StonePriceWindow(CostSimulator *parent) : ui(new Ui::StonePriceWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
displayStonePriceList(parent);
}

Comment: Right, so there are two `StonePriceWindow` classes, one in the `Ui` namespace, and it's that which is causing the problem.  I'd suggest looking at ui_stonepricewindow.h

Comment: `Ui::StonePriceWindow` is generated by the `uic` and so should be right - it should also _only_ have a compiler created constructor.  Have you tried just performing a full clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes i tried right click and clean project, but did nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
In the StonePrinceWindow.ui, there was an obsolete name of the UI, so the auto-generated ui_stonepricewindow keep the obsolete name (even after a clean) and the compiler never find the ctor.

Comment: You explained the problem, but not the solution.  How did you fix this?  I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I could not add a comment on the best answer..

I had a similar problem too, it appeared that there was a mismatch between the classname of the code I created and the dialogs' objectName property value in the Qt .ui file.

I opened the .ui file in QtDesigner, and changed the objectName property value to the classname I had used in my code. Afterwards compilation was going fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding StonePriceWindow(){}  and removing the default parameter for the other constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But there is exactly the same problem ` public:
    StonePriceWindow(){}
    StonePriceWindow(CostSimulator *parent);
    ~StonePriceWindow();` and always stonepricewindow.cpp:7: erreur : C2512: 'Ui::StonePriceWindow' : no appropriate default constructor available

Answer (score 0):

When you write code like

```
StonePriceWindow x;
```

how does compiler know whether you call the parameterless constructor or another one with default value for `parent`?

You need to either remove the other one, or remove the default value from it.

Comment: Where is that written in the provided code? And the `StonePriceWindow` class does not have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: That is not written in the code, but compiler needs to instantiate the object somewhere with code which is functionaly equal. `StonePriceWindow` doesn't have parameterless ctor, so he added one - see last sentence of the question: "if I had this 'StonePriceWindow() {}' to the header... "

Comment: `new Ui::StonePriceWindow` called in `StonePriceWindow` ctor implementation is the 'functionally equal' to `StonePriceWindow x`.

Comment: I understand what is happening, but the OP clearly doesn't, so providing a rather cryptic answer that doesn't obviously relate to the code in the question - isn't helping anyone.  Edit your answer to make it obvious why the OP is getting this error _from the code posted_ and I'll upvote you.

Comment: The only moment i call my ctor is for `StonePriceWindow *stonepricewindow = new StonePriceWindow(this);` if I add `StonePriceWindow(){}` in header and remove the default value for my actual ctor, I have the same error.

Comment: @user2102526 no, you also call it here: `StonePriceWindow::StonePriceWindow(CostSimulator *parent) : ui(new Ui::StonePriceWindow)`. see that part after `new`? that's your ctor call, exactly as compiler error states/

Comment: Yes I know, but I can't understand why I have the same error, even if I added `StonePriceWindow(){}`

Comment: @cmannett85 my answer explains why you can't have both parameterless ctor and one with only default parameters - not where is the error in his code, as it is clearly stated in compiler error. The last sentence of the question shows the confusion that I try to explain.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the strings

```
#ifndef COSTSIMULATOR_H
#define COSTSIMULATOR_H
```

in either of the files costsimulator.h and ui_costsimulator.h

Qt places the same `#ifndef #define` expression in auto generated ui_costsimulator.h